# JavaFX - Cannot call setOnAction() on ChoiceBox?

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx, event-handling

Simple question:

I've DEFINITELY used `setOnAction` for `ChoiceBox<T>` before, but it claims there is no such method of the `ChoiceBox` class. I'm using a different computer and have installed the `Ex(fx)clipse` plugin. At the bottom of this thread are my imports. I also have proof that [I have used this method of ChoiceBox before](https://github.com/KevinTyrrell/Diablo2BankTracker/blob/master/src/application/GUI.java#L668). What is wrong? It must be something outrageously simple. I don't understand how I was able to write it before and yet I don't see it in the [JavaFX API page](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/ChoiceBox.html).

## Edit:

[Runnable version of my class here](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/3a944864fd522d325bed).

**Instance Variables**

```
private VBox root;
private Scene scene;
private static Stage stage;
private Label consoleTitle;
private static TextArea console;
private Button startBtn, endBtn, calibrateBtn, calibrateAreaBtn;
private ChoiceBox<String> lureCB;
private CheckBox lureCKB;
private HBox buttonHB, lureHB;
```

**Code block in my method body:**

```
// ChoiceBox for the type of lures.
lureCB = new ChoiceBox<>();
lureCB.getItems().addAll("Test",
        "Test",
        "Test",
        "Test",
        "Test",
        "Test");
lureCB.setVisible(false);
lureCB.setOnAction(e ->
{

});
```

[image]

**My Imports**

```
package gui;

import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.time.LocalTime;

import program.*;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.Region;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.control.CheckBox;
import javafx.scene.control.ChoiceBox;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;
import javafx.scene.control.Tooltip;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
```

Comment: If you set your EventHandler somewhere else and reference this object at setOnAction method does it work?

Comment: @Apostolos I've actually never made an `Event Handler` outside of a `.setOn______` method. How is that done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### EDIT:

It turned out that the `setOnAction` method was only added to the `ChoiceBox` API starting from the **8u60** version of the JDK.

[image]

Comment: @Hatefiend one sec, the quick fix says: **Add a cast to lureCb**... what does that give you as a result ? Are you sure that the `lureCb` reference is in deed a `ChoiceBox<String>` ?

Comment: What's weird is if I click that cast, it tries to cast `lureCB` to a `ButtonBase`. This happens whether `e` is casted to an `ActionEvent` or not. [see here](http://i.imgur.com/nxxNwRC.png). Remember that `lureCB` is just the variable name for my `ChoiceBox<String>`, it's not a type. It's as if Java thinks it's a type or something.

[Here is the link to my GUI class](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/a36cfb5cecd783312581).

Comment: hum, that's weird. Try using an explicit anonymous class instead: `lureCb.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() { ... });` and override the **handle** method.

Comment: I added a runnable version of my project without an dependencies. It will run standalone. There's one boolean method that you can just type `return false` in to make it compile. In this project however, [I am still getting the same error](http://i.imgur.com/iQZye79.png). You can find this runnable version in my original post.

Comment: Have you tried using an anonymous class (like mentioned above) ?

Comment: Yep. [Same thing](http://i.imgur.com/ZrBzFj9.png). `The method setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>(){}) is undefined for the type ChoiceBox<String>`. That is with the import `import javafx.event.EventHandler;`. This is SO weird.